# Working with Classes - Invalid allocation size

Tags: c++, arrays, class

i have homework, but it is not working. Best i can guess as to why it is not working is an auto breakpoint to vs2013 which displays this in the output box.

`HEAP[hw2_ccc.exe]: Invalid allocation size - 10 (exceeded fffdefff)`

`First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD9D940D in hw2_ccc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x000000000012F350.`

`HEAP[hw2_ccc.exe]: Invalid allocation size - 1 (exceeded fffdefff)`

`First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD9D940D in hw2_ccc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x000000000012CE40.`

`First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD9D940D in hw2_ccc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.`

`First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD9D940D in hw2_ccc.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x000000000012CE40.`

`A buffer overrun has occurred in hw2_ccc.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state.`

Here is my code:

bankAccount.h

```
#ifndef H_bankAccount
#define H_bankAccount

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class bankAccount
{
public:
    void setAccountName(string holderName);
    void setAccountNumber(int accountNumber);
    void setInterestRate(double interestRate);
    void setAccountType(string accountType);
    void depositBalance(double deposit);
    void withdrawBalance(double withdraw);
    void printAccountInformation();
    void newAccount(string holderName, int accountNumber, string accountType, double interestRate);
    string getAccountName();
    bankAccount();
    ~bankAccount();

private:
    string holderName;
    int accountNumber;
    string accountType;
    double balance;
    double interestRate;

};
#endif
```

bankAccount.cpp

```
#include "bankAccount.h"

using namespace std;

bankAccount::bankAccount()
{

}

bankAccount::~bankAccount()
{

}

void bankAccount::newAccount(string holderName, int accountNumber, string accountType, double interestRate)
{
    setAccountName(holderName);
    setAccountNumber(accountNumber);
    setAccountType(accountType);
    setInterestRate(interestRate);
}

void bankAccount::setAccountName(string holderName)
{
    bankAccount::holderName = holderName;
}

void bankAccount::setAccountNumber(int accountNumber)
{
    bankAccount::accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

void bankAccount::setAccountType(string accountType)
{
    bankAccount::accountType = accountType;
}

void bankAccount::setInterestRate(double interestRate)
{
    bankAccount::interestRate = interestRate;
}

void bankAccount::depositBalance(double deposit)
{
    bankAccount::balance += deposit;
}

void bankAccount::withdrawBalance(double withdraw)
{
    bankAccount::balance -= withdraw;
}

void bankAccount::printAccountInformation()
{
    cout << "Account Name: " << bankAccount::holderName << endl;
    cout << "Account Type: " << bankAccount::accountType << endl;
    cout << "Account Number: " << bankAccount::accountNumber << endl;
    cout << "Account Interest Rate: " << bankAccount::interestRate << endl;
    cout << "Account Balance :" << bankAccount::balance << endl;
}

string bankAccount::getAccountName()
{
    return holderName;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "bankAccount.h"

using namespace std;

int randAccountNum();
string randAccountType();
int interestRate(string accountType);
bool printAccount(bankAccount accounts[10]);

int main()
{
    bankAccount account[10];
    string accountNames[10] = { "Bob", "Jack", "Billy", "James", "Kathy", "John", "Jenny", "Penny", "Sue", "Louis" };
    string accountType;
    int accountNumber;
    bool prAcc = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(account); i++)
    {
        accountType = randAccountType();
        accountNumber = randAccountNum();
        account[i].newAccount(accountNames[i], accountNumber, accountType, interestRate(accountType));
    }

    while (prAcc)
    {
        prAcc = printAccount(account);
    }

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}

int randAccountNum()
{
    int num = rand() % 1000 + 1;
    return num;
}

string randAccountType()
{
    string str;
    int num = rand() % 2 + 1;
    if (num = 1)
    {
        str = "Savings";
    }
    else {
        str = "Checking";
    }

    return str;
}

int interestRate(string accountType)
{
    int ir;

    if (accountType == "Savings")
    {
        ir = 2;
    }
    else {
        ir = 4;
    }

    return ir;
}    

bool printAccount(bankAccount accounts[10])
{
    string cont;
    bool contL = true;
    string accountName;

    cout << "Enter account name: ";
    cin >> accountName;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(accounts); i++)
    {
        if (accounts[i].getAccountName() == accountName)
        {
            accounts[i].printAccountInformation();
        }
    }




    while (contL)
    {
        cout << "Enter another name? (Yes/No): ";
        cin >> cont;
        if (cont == "Yes")
            return true;
        else if (cont == "No")
            return false;
        else
            cout << "Invalid. Please enter Yes or No" << endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: ekhm.... `for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(accounts); i++)`

Comment: Why not just use `std::vector`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code:

> ```
> bankAccount account[10];
>
> ...
>
> for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(account); i++)
> ```

You have a problem in loop iteration (in particular, in the *upper bound*).

Your `account` array contains 10 instances of your `bankAccount` class.
It's clear that your intent is to iterate through all the array items. For that to work correctly, valid values for the `i` loop index are 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 9. So, this would work if `sizeof(account)` returned 10 (in fact, you use the `<` operator, to exclude the upper limit of 10, and just stopping one value before, at 9, which is correct).

The problem is that `sizeof(account)` does return the **size in bytes** of the `account` array. This is equivalent to `10 * sizeof(bankAccount)`, where again `sizeof(bankAccount)` returns the size in bytes of your `bankAccount` class. Assuming that your `bankAccount` class' size is e.g. 40 bytes, then `sizeof(account)` becomes `10 * 40`, i.e. 400 bytes.

So, in this case, in your `for` loop, your index spans values **`0,1,2,3,4,...9,`** `10,11,12,...399`: the values in **bold** are valid, the next ones are not!

You have what is called a *buffer overrun*, which is clearly stated in the VC++ compiler's error message:

> ```
> [...] A buffer overrun has occurred
> ```

To fix that problem, you have several options.

For example, to get the proper item count, you can divide the *total* size (in bytes) of the array, by the size of *one* of its elements, e.g. the first one, at index 0:

```
// Count of items in the 'account' array
const int accountCount = sizeof(account) / sizeof(account[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < accountCount; i++)
    ...
```

Another option is to use a more modern C++ approach, e.g. using C++11's **`std::array`**:

```
#include <array>   // for std::array
...

// Define an array of 10 bankAccount's
std::array<bankAccount, 10> account;

// Note that account.size() is 10!
// i.e., this is the size in *element count* (not in bytes, like sizeof()).
for (int i = 0; i < account.size(); i++)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I took your advice on using the modern approach and used the array. Worked very well. You explained in a clear manner and was spot on.

Answer (score 4):

Change this  statement

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(account); i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(account) / sizeof(*account); i++)
```

Also there is error in function

bool printAccount(bankAccount accounts[10]);

In this statement

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(accounts); i++)
```

sizeof(accounts) is equal to sizeof( bankAccount * )

You have to declare a second parameter for the size of the array passed to the function.

Take into account that you could use objects of type  `std::array` unstead of the arrays.  In this case there would not be such problems with the sizes of the arrays.

Comment: Why not just use `account.size()`?

Comment: @Calpratt What is account.size()?

Comment: Wait nope, I'm dumb.
Was thinking of the container library array

Comment: @Calpratt I have just written about it in my post.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This was along the lines of what i was looking for, but Mr.C64 had a more clear and explained answer.